# Converting negative number to IP address python

Tags: python-3.x, ip, ip-address

and i am trying to convert long numbers to IP address but python doesnt allow me to convert -ve values to long. Below are my functions, can anyone please help?

## Convert ip addess from string to integer

```
def get_ip_address_int(ip_address):
    return struct.unpack("!L", socket.inet_aton(ip_address))[0]

# Convert ip adress from integer to string
def get_ip_address_str(ip_address):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L',ip_address))
```

ip_address = -1277278613

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what happens if you try `socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L',(ip_address+2**32)%2**32)`?

Comment: To be sure: are you getting *"struct.error: argument out of range"*?

Answer (score 2):

`L` means *unsigned* long. `-1277278613` is signed. Assuming that input must be 32bit (ipv4) then `-1277278613` may correspond to different bit patterns depending on byte order:

```
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('<i', -1277278613))
'107.70.222.179'
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>i', -1277278613))
'179.222.70.107'
```

if the sign is not preserved then you shouldn't assume the network byte order (big-endian) either.

If you think the input uses the native byte-order; you could use `=` (standard size):

```
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('=i', -1277278613))
'107.70.222.179'
```